# Wordpress dbdelta: no errors, no results, no response

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am trying to create a Wordpress plugin. The code for setting up the database tables will be provided shortly. However the problem I'm facing is not not an error as much as a lack thereof. No matter what I do, dbdelta seems to do absolutely nothing - and wordpress will not generate any relevant error to at least give me a clue on what's going wrong.

The code is:

```
function create_tables()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $pl_nm = VSystem::$plugin_name;
    $create_voters = "create table if not exists {$wpdb->prefix}{$pl_nm}_voters(
        ID bigint(20) unsigned auto_increment,
        user_id bigint(20) unsigned not null,
        primary key  (ID),
        foreign key (user_id) references {$wpdb->prefix}users(ID)
    );";

    $create_links = "create table if not exists {$wpdb->prefix}{$pl_nm}_links(
        ID bigint(20) unsigned auto_increment,
        product bigint(20) unsigned,
        name varchar(256) not null,
        url varchar(512) not null,
        description text,
        posted datetime,
        poster bigint(20) unsigned not null,
        primary key  (ID),
        foreign key (poster) references {$wpdb->prefix}users(ID)
    );";

    $create_votes = "create table if not exists {$wpdb->prefix}{$pl_nm}_votes(
        ID bigint(20) unsigned auto_increment,
        link_id bigint(20) unsigned not null,
        voter_id bigint(20) unsigned not null,
        choice int not null,
        primary key  (ID),
        foreign key (link_id) references {$wpdb->prefix}{$pl_nm}_links(ID),
        foreign key (voter_id) references {$wpdb->prefix}users(ID)
    );";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $create_voters );
    dbDelta( $create_links );
    dbDelta( $create_votes );
    dbDelta("asdasdsadsad");
    //wp_die("{$wpdb->prefix}{$pl_nm}");



    add_option('db_version', VSystem::$defaults['db_version']);
}

function vsystem_install()
{
    create_tables();
}
```

Now I know this function is being called at least because uncommenting the wp_die command acts as it is supposed to. Can I get any help?

```
    dbDelta("asdasdsadsad");
```

Not even that seems to generate any kind of response. I might be able to do this on my own if someone could tell me how to get dbdelta to do anything.

Comment: in wp-config.php did you set WP_DEBUG to true? ie `define('WP_DEBUG', true)` otherwise you won't be able to see any errors

Comment: WOW.

So for anyone who ever has the misfortune of running into this problem again.

1) foreign key seems problematic - but hey, its just a hobbyist level website CMS so I doubt referential integrity is a big deal.

2) create table should be CAPITALIZED. I have no idea why but doing so made the query work with no other changes (other than truncating the foreign key).

----

3) This function and Wordpress in general are not in a habit of giving concise error reports - if at all.

@Ahmad I'll look into it.

Comment: sql syntax doesn't have to be capitalized, You just didn't have error reporting turned on, I think :)

Comment: Nope. Those 2 problems were independant. It of course, could be any number of possible things that happened. But I hadn't dont anything with debug. Or my code. i literally just capitalized the sql to see if anything would happen.

Comment: @Yuma: Can you include your new code in an answer and accept it? I, and probably others, would really like to see your truncated foreign key syntax.